# How do I get to display the data i've retrieved from MyBatis in a collections property?

Tags: mybatis

This is my mapper:

```
<mapper namespace="mybatis.mappers.ParentMapper">
    <resultMap id="Parent" type="parentBean">
        <result column="PARENT_ID"      property="parentID" />
        <result column="PARENT_NAME"    property="parentName" />
        <collection column="CHILD_NAME" property="children"  ofType="String" javaType="ArrayList"/>
    </resultMap>

    <select id="retrieveParentsFromDB" resultMap="Parent">
        SELECT      PARENT_ID, P.PARENT_NAME, CHILD_NAME, C.idchildren
        FROM        MYBATIS.PARENTS P, MYBATIS.CHILDREN C
        WHERE       P.PARENT_NAME = 'PARENT A' 
        ORDER BY    P.PARENT_ID, C.CHILD_NAME; 
    </select>
</mapper>
```

The CHILD_NAME COLUMN field denotes the children's names. But when I print out the values in a java file. What is retrieved seems to be the parent ID values. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out adding a column property in the collections property tag means you would use it in a nested query. I used this instead

```
<collection property="children"  ofType="String" javaType="ArrayList">
    <result column="CHILD_NAME" />
</collection>
```